# Alternatives to Python PasteScript's paster create?

Tags: python, project

It seems like [PasteScript](http://pythonpaste.org/script/)'s `paster create` functionality is just about the only widely used  framework for building/generating a project skeleton within python. I'm wondering if there are any alternatives in the python world that folks use?

**Update**

I want to comment on my experience since originally asking this question. The accepted answer still stands - there are a number of templating/skeleton packages out there one could use. 
However, from the other answers given, I did start to use [mr.bob](https://github.com/iElectric/mr.bob) and have checked out [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter). Both are **generic** (as in not bound to a particular framework), **easy to use** and relatively **current** and **active** projects - which were part of the criteria I was looking for but did not detail in my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your framework. For Django applications, you [use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) `django-admin.py startproject mysite`. For developing GUI applications on Linux, there's [Ubuntu's Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly), which also creates a skeleton project. For Paste projects, you use paster.

There's not really a general purpose tool for what you're doing though. It depends on the framework, and usually, those scripts come with particular frameworks. And for what it's worth, [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (an IDE) includes some project templates for things like [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a general purpose tool. Something I can use to create my own project templates. As you point out, every framework/environment seems to implement its own version of a project generation tool.

Comment: What you're asking for really just doesn't exist, at least not in a well-known package that's widely supported.

Comment: +1 for mentioning IDE support for templates. I now use a combination of cookiecutter and the build in template feature of my IDE. First I pull a template from cookiecutter. Then I open the template with my IDE and adjust it to my needs. Finally I save the adjusted state of the cookiecutter template as a new IDE project template. I can now select the template when I open the 'create new project' dialog in my IDE (IntelliJ Idea)

Answer (score 16):

I'm rather partial to [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter). It works for Python 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, and PyPy on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows. It's fully documented, actively maintained, well tested, and really easy to use. Here is my [blog entry](http://pydanny.com/cookie-project-templates-made-easy.html) on it. It even has its own Stack Overflow tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cookiecutter

Comment: Thanks for pointing out [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) - looks very good and I like the name.

Answer (score 5):

"Skeleton" looks very promising.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/skeleton/

Answer (score 4):

As I'm in the process of releasing **mr.bob** 0.1a6, it is mostly feature complete as PasteScript. It is a general purpose directory skeleton generator that shouldn't require Python knowledge to write new skeletons.

Documentation: http://mrbob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [Python Packager](https://github.com/fcurella/python-packager) that I just ran across while searching for these types of tools.  It appears to have a fairly narrow use case, but it might nice for those looking for help pulling OSS license files.