# Python 3 Project Initialization / Prototyping

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for the correct way to prototype, initiate a Python project.

- [PasteScript](http://pythonpaste.org/script/) has not been updated to Python 3.
- [Skeleton](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/skeleton/) is available fror 3.1 but has not been maintained for the last two years.
- [Step by Step Guide](http://foobar.lu/wp/2012/05/13/a-comprehensive-step-through-python-packaging-a-k-a-setup-scripts/) gives information to manually create the structure of a project for packaging.
- [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/index.html)

Is there any new candidate for starting a project and populating all the files necessary for the project?

Comment: @Efazati I'm not planning to use any framework for simple scripts. I will do it by hand if necessary but that would be nice to have a little script kickstarting everything: README, licenses, directories for test cases, etc.

Comment: A similar question but [without the good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356190/alternatives-to-python-pastescripts-paster-create)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly what I was looking for but it will do the job.

- [A Project Skeleton](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html)
- [Another project skeleton](https://github.com/fcurella/python-package-skeleton) to download on Github.
- [How to Package your Python Code](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/)

Adding new information

- [Cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) seems exactly what it requires to initialize and start a project. See [a blog posts explaining it](http://pydanny.com/cookie-project-templates-made-easy.html).
- [Cookiecutter for libraries](https://github.com/ionelmc/cookiecutter-pylibrary)